# pairwise column comparison in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to calculate a score for two columns from two different dataframes. Based on some other post here, I cross-joined the two data frames and trying to calculate as below. But for some reason I am getting the same score for every pair.

Here is an example:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import process
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

>>> l = [('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('saurabh',20),('Bala',26)]
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
>>> people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1])))
>>> schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
>>> schemaPeople.show()
+---+--------+
|age|    name|
+---+--------+
| 25|   Ankit|
| 22|Jalfaizy|
| 20| saurabh|
| 26|    Bala|
+---+--------+

>>> schemaPeople_dup.show()
+-------+--------+
|dup_age|dup_name|
+-------+--------+
|     25|   Ankit|
|     22|Jalfaizy|
|     20| saurabh|
|     26|    Bala|
+-------+--------+

>>> cross = schemaPeople.crossJoin(schemaPeople_dup)
>>> cross.show()
+---+--------+-------+--------+
|age|    name|dup_age|dup_name|
+---+--------+-------+--------+
| 25|   Ankit|     25|   Ankit|
| 25|   Ankit|     22|Jalfaizy|
| 25|   Ankit|     20| saurabh|
| 25|   Ankit|     26|    Bala|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     25|   Ankit|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     22|Jalfaizy|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     20| saurabh|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     26|    Bala|
| 20| saurabh|     25|   Ankit|
| 20| saurabh|     22|Jalfaizy|
| 20| saurabh|     20| saurabh|
| 20| saurabh|     26|    Bala|
| 26|    Bala|     25|   Ankit|
| 26|    Bala|     22|Jalfaizy|
| 26|    Bala|     20| saurabh|
| 26|    Bala|     26|    Bala|
+---+--------+-------+--------+

>> cross.withColumn("score", lit(fuzz.token_sort_ratio(cross["name"], cross["dup_name"]))).show()
+---+--------+-------+--------+-----+
|age|    name|dup_age|dup_name|score|
+---+--------+-------+--------+-----+
| 25|   Ankit|     25|   Ankit|   85|
| 25|   Ankit|     22|Jalfaizy|   85|
| 25|   Ankit|     20| saurabh|   85|
| 25|   Ankit|     26|    Bala|   85|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     25|   Ankit|   85|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     22|Jalfaizy|   85|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     20| saurabh|   85|
| 22|Jalfaizy|     26|    Bala|   85|
| 20| saurabh|     25|   Ankit|   85|
| 20| saurabh|     22|Jalfaizy|   85|
| 20| saurabh|     20| saurabh|   85|
| 20| saurabh|     26|    Bala|   85|
| 26|    Bala|     25|   Ankit|   85|
| 26|    Bala|     22|Jalfaizy|   85|
| 26|    Bala|     20| saurabh|   85|
| 26|    Bala|     26|    Bala|   85|
+---+--------+-------+--------+-----+
```

Which doesnt make any sense as, the score needs to be different. Not sure where is this 
85 coming from.

```
>>> fuzz.token_sort_ratio("Ankit","Ankit")
100
>>> fuzz.token_sort_ratio("Ankit","Jalfaizy")
31
```

Also, how can I calculate the mean score of different columns.

```
statistics.mean([fuzz.token_sort_ratio("col1",dup_col1"), fuzz.token_sort_ratio("col2",dup_col2"), fuzz.token_sort_ratio("col3",dup_col3")])
```

Comment: You've used `lit` which gives the entire column a single value inside that function call. Can you try using it without `lit`? Like `>> cross.withColumn("score", fuzz.token_sort_ratio(cross["name"], cross["dup_name"])).show()`. I'm not sure if you'll need a `udf` for this.

Comment: you should remove lit and use udf to apply on columns.

Comment: Without using 'lit' I am getting the below error:                                                assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
AssertionError: col should be Column